# How to Find the n-th most similar value

Tags: excel

The goal is to find the two most similar operational days, and return their averages for the production measurements. This will help future operational planning.

So I have a list of facilities and their operational data for the past 90 days. So each facility will have one row per day. This info is on its own worksheet, and is pulled in from an excel-based query. So essentially this tab "PDA" has the columns "Facility", "Date", and "Total Output".

On the 2nd tab, "Analyzer", I have a similar set up. But its for future dates. What I want to do is take the "CPWTotal" (total output for the future dates) and find the two most similar days from the "PDA" tab and return those two "Total Outputs". I tried using a mash up of a index(small) and min(abs) function to find the smallest differences, but it didn't work nearly as well as I hoped.

Below is the closest I've gotten, but the comparison to building number has been a major hang up.

PDA!AB contains the historical output data, PDA!W contains the historical data building number, A3 contains the future plan building number, and C3 contains the future output forecast.

```
{=INDEX(PDA!$AB$2:$AB$10000,MATCH(($A3 = PDA!$W$2:$W$10000)*MIN(ABS(PDA!$AB$2:$AB$10000-$C3)),ABS(PDA!$AB$2:$AB$10000-$C3),0))}
```

I know the ()*Min() portion might be tripping me up, but my logic was that is would be 0*Min() if the building number was not a match, thus returning a 0 for that line of the match, and I have not been able to figure out a better approach.

This isn't the last step, but its what I need to set up the index(match) to pull the rest of the operational data that I need to average out.

I am also open to VBA solutions.

EDIT: Sample Data:

Tab 1: PDA Return (worksheet where I want the output to be returned) 1 and 2 are the columns where the closest and 2nd closest match will be returned.

Bulding #   2016    CPW Forecast    1   2

4505    29-Feb-16   1789
4505    01-Mar-16   2270
4505    02-Mar-16   2108
4505    03-Mar-16   2028
4505    04-Mar-16   1912
4600    29-Feb-16   1653
4600    01-Mar-16   2264
4600    02-Mar-16   2232
4600    03-Mar-16   2013
4600    04-Mar-16   1876
4650    29-Feb-16   1799
4650    01-Mar-16   2254
4650    02-Mar-16   2181
4650    03-Mar-16   1902
4650    04-Mar-16   1910

Tab 2 (PDA) contains the info I want to search for:

Building #  2016    CPW Total Production

4505    29-Feb-16   1799
4505    01-Mar-16   2250
4505    02-Mar-16   2118
4505    03-Mar-16   2025
4505    04-Mar-16   1914
4600    29-Feb-16   1654
4600    01-Mar-16   2262
4600    02-Mar-16   2231
4600    03-Mar-16   2016
4600    04-Mar-16   1826
4650    29-Feb-16   1789
4650    01-Mar-16   2244
4650    02-Mar-16   2161
4650    03-Mar-16   1912
4650    04-Mar-16   1920

I don't know how to upload a sample excel file but you should be able to just copy/paste those tables.

Comment: I don't understand.  It may help if you post representative data and demonstrate what you want to obtain.

Comment: What is "building number"?  Is it the same as "facility"?

Comment: I don't know what `n-th most similar` means.  Perhaps it would help to know more about your overall goal.

Comment: Building # and facility number are the same. They are 4 digit identifier numbers that are unique to each building. 


N-th most would be like closest comparison, 2nd closest, and then 3rd closest.  So say the target number is 2210. So then 2205 would be the closest, with 2216 being the 2nd....etc. I would like to be able to find n-th match for future project purposes. 


Ill post something here shortly, for a sample. Once I figure out exactly how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to use a pseudo-MINIFS twice; once to return the minimum days differential and again to return the first matching row number.

> <sup>For the purpose of dynamic range allocation, the following will define the extents of each range by the row number of the last date in column AB. The range `PDA!W$2:W$14` becomes,</sup>
>
> ```
> PDA!W$2:INDEX(PDA!W:W, MATCH(1E+99, PDA!AB:AB))
> ```
>
> <sub>All ranges will be defined this way. Full column references should **not** be used with the [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF). Additions and deletions of data will be automatically adjusted for</sub>

**[Standard Formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-functions-by-category-5f91f4e9-7b42-46d2-9bd1-63f26a86c0eb) for [excel-2010](/questions/tagged/excel-2010)**

The standard formula in D3 is,

```
=INDEX(PDA!$AC:$AC,
       AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(PDA!AC$2:INDEX(PDA!AC:AC, MATCH(1E+99, PDA!AB:AB )))/
     ((PDA!W$2:INDEX(PDA!W:W, MATCH(1E+99, PDA!AB:AB ))=A$3)*
      (ABS(PDA!AB$2:INDEX(PDA!AB:AB, MATCH(1E+99, PDA!AB:AB))-C$3)=
       AGGREGATE(15,6,ABS(PDA!AB$2:INDEX(PDA!AB:AB, MATCH(1E+99, PDA!AB:AB ))-C$3)/
      (PDA!W$2:INDEX(PDA!W:W, MATCH(1E+99, PDA!AB:AB ))=A$3),1))),ROW(1:1)))
```

That returns the first match. Fill down for the second, third, etc matches if they exist.

[image]
            <sup>[Sample data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/How%20to%20Find%20the%20n-th%20most%20similar%20value.xlsx) from [excel-2010] solution.</sup>

Comment: I cannot get it to return anything other than the 1st closest match. Tried changing the ROW(1,1) portion at the end but it either gave me the 1st match or an #NUM! error.